# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView, recyclerview content is not visible unless specify height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

[image]`RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView`, `RecyclerView` is expecting to specify its height, if we not specify height `RecyclerView` is not visible.

Is this issue or expected?

Comment: Avoid such situations, in the case of `recyclerView` use items with multiple types.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve with nested scrollview? coz. it is already implemented :(

Comment: I canot use single Recyclerview because first 9 item is of staggerd like and other item is just linear (normal item) ,so here am using two recycler(inside Nested scrollview) view one for staggerd and other for linear type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is expected, think about it, there are two scrolling parents, how and when can the behavior be classified if the height of one was not specified, since the height constrains and delimits the extent of scrolling for `recyclerview`, if match parent, is used a confusion is guaranteed, see where i am going with this?

Comment: that is the effect of nested scrolling after all .

Comment: then how can i specify height? because height of child is come to know at run time...

Comment: you need read upon scrolling behavior of a coordinator layout first.

Comment: Reyclerview can support multiple item views, just inflate it That is the easiest and most consistent way in handling such a scenario.

Comment: Ok is there any way to achieve with nested scrollview? coz. it is already implemented :(

Comment: i achieved like this:

DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mGridRecycler.getLayoutParams();

        params.height=height/1.2;

Comment: above code is working all most all device but in some device recyclerview height is slightly bigger than actual item,so keeping blank whitespace at bottom..

Comment: so it is the blank space?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139168/discussion-between-ram-and-caspain-caldion).